# Laravel Trait with constructor works in controller but not in model

Tags: php, stripe-payments, laravel-9

I have a StripeClient service provider which needs a key to instantiate:-

```php
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\DeferrableProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Stripe\StripeClient;

class StripeServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider implements DeferrableProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(StripeClient::class, function ($app) {
            return new StripeClient(config('services.stripe.secret'));
        });
    }
    
    /**
     * Get the services provided by the provider.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function provides()
    {
        return [StripeClient::class];
    }
```

Then a trait with a bunch of api call functions like this:-

```php
trait StripeClientTrait
{
    protected $stripe;
    
    function __construct(StripeClient $stripeClient)
    {
        $this->stripe = $stripeClient;
    }
    
    /**
     * @param  User  $user
     *
     * @return \Stripe\Customer
     * @throws \Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException
     */
    function createCustomer(User $user)
    {
        return $this->stripe->customers->create([  'name' => $user->fullname,
                                                   'email' => $user->email
                                                ]);
    }
    ...
```

The trait works in a controller perfectly as expected:-

```php
class SubscriptionContoller extends Controller
{
    use StripeClientTrait;
    
    public function checkout()
    {
        try {
            $customer = $this->createCustomer(Auth::user());
            if($checkoutSession = $this->createCheckoutSession($customer)) {
                return redirect($checkoutSession->url);
            }
            
        } catch (ApiErrorException $ex){
            Log::error($ex->getMessage());
            return back()->with(['error'=>$ex->getMessage()]);
        }
        
        return back();
    }
    

    ...
```

But I now need to use the trait in a model to provide access to some api functions.

```php
class Company extends Tenant
{
    use HasFactory, StripeClientTrait;
```

but adding the trait causes:-

> Too few arguments to function App\Models\Company::__construct(), 0 passed in /home/vagrant/code/profiler/vendor/spatie/laravel-multitenancy/src/Models/Concerns/UsesTenantModel.php on line 13 and exactly 1 expected

Can anyone tell me how to implement the trait without using the constructor?  I just need some static function helpers to lookup stuff on the API.

Thanks for any guidance :-)

Answer (score 0):

having persevered I've found this way to use the service container in a model:-

```php
public function getPrices()
    {
        $stripe = app(StripeClient::class);
        return $stripe->prices->all(['active'=>true]);
    }
```

But would still like to understand how to use the trait in the model, if anyone could explain I'd be grateful